# Insert and converting date columns into different SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following `StagingTable` in my SQL Server database:

```
     Date1               Date2
2020-10-19 04:00    20-10-18 16:42:32
```

These are both setup as `varchar(max)` column types.

I am trying to send them over to my main `Table` which are setup as `datetime2(7)` column types.

I have used the following code:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table]
    SELECT 
        CONVERT(datetime2, [Date1]),
        CONVERT(datetime2, [Date2])
    FROM 
        [dbo].[StagingTable]
```

but when I run the query I get the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Any ideas on how to get around this and effectively insert across? I have done this before and usually the `convert function works. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: your varchar date should be in correct format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm.  Your second value has a two digit year, which is an issue.  You might try:

```
coalesce(try_convert(datetime2(7), date1),
         try_convert(datetime2(7), '20' + date1)
        ),
coalesce(try_convert(datetime2(7), date2),
         try_convert(datetime2(7), '20' + date2)
        )
```

Presumably, the two-digit year could appear in either column.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b2d5bb1e98950a5ce3b56d40ef03b429) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

try chance this

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table]
SELECT convert(datetime2,[Date1],101)
  ,convert(datetime2,[Date2],2)

 FROM [dbo].[StagingTable]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Still the same unfortunately! I gathered its something to do with the formats but just not quite sure how to get around it!

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: The original data comes from a python dataframe which goes into the `StagingTable` as a `varchar(max)` and when i tried running your script it gives the same error `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

Comment: for your sample its work if you had different data i don't know exactly